# SQL Query with 4 subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2014

Why does one of these subquery methods work and the other not work? What would be a more efficient way to structure this data?

I have a entity table and then a time series table the corresponds to those entities with different types of production data.  I'm trying to get the first dates for each production streams.

I tried Query A first and it was still crunching after 3 hours.  Query B works almost instantly.

There are 255 rows in the entities table and ~150000 rows in the times series table.  Running SQL Server 2014.

Query A: (didn't work)

```
select 
    main.PROPNUM
    ,min(sub_fluid.d_date) as [first_fluid]
    ,min(sub_hc.d_date) as [first_hydrocarbon]
    ,min(sub_oil.d_date) as [first_oil]
    ,min(sub_gas.d_date) as [first_gas]
from daily_production as main

left join
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,(oil+gas+water) as fluid
    from daily_production
    where (oil+gas+water) > 0
    )  as sub_fluid
on main.PROPNUM = sub_fluid.PROPNUM

left join
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,(oil+gas) as hydrocarbon
    from daily_production
    where (oil+gas) > 0
    )  as sub_hc

on main.PROPNUM = sub_hc.PROPNUM

left join
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,oil
    from daily_production
    where (oil) > 0
    )  as sub_oil
on main.PROPNUM = sub_oil.PROPNUM

left join
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,gas
    from daily_production
    where (gas) > 0
    )  as sub_gas
on main.PROPNUM = sub_gas.PROPNUM

group by main.PROPNUM
```

Query B: (Works Great)

```
select
    daily_production.propnum
    ,first_fluid.first_fluid
    ,first_hydrocarbon.first_hydrocarbon
    ,first_oil.first_oil
    ,first_gas.first_gas

from daily_production

left join

(select 
    sub_fluid.PROPNUM
    ,min(sub_fluid.d_date) as [first_fluid]
from
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,(oil+gas+water) as fluid
    from daily_production
    where (oil+gas+water) > 0
    )  as sub_fluid
group by PROPNUM) as first_fluid

on daily_production.PROPNUM = first_fluid.PROPNUM

left join

(select 
    sub_hc.PROPNUM
    ,min(sub_hc.d_date) as [first_hydrocarbon]
from
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,(oil+gas) as hydrocarbon
    from daily_production
    where (oil+gas) > 0
    )  as sub_hc
group by PROPNUM) as first_hydrocarbon

on daily_production.PROPNUM = first_hydrocarbon.PROPNUM

left join

(select 
    sub_oil.PROPNUM
    ,min(sub_oil.d_date) as [first_oil]
from
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,(oil) 
    from daily_production
    where (oil) > 0
    )  as sub_oil
group by PROPNUM) as first_oil

on daily_production.PROPNUM = first_oil.PROPNUM

left join

(select 
    sub_gas.PROPNUM
    ,min(sub_gas.d_date) as [first_gas]
from
    (
    select
        PROPNUM
        ,D_DATE
        ,(gas) 
    from daily_production
    where (gas) > 0
    )  as sub_gas
group by PROPNUM) as first_gas

on daily_production.PROPNUM = first_gas.PROPNUM

group by daily_production.PROPNUM, first_fluid.first_fluid, first_hydrocarbon.first_hydrocarbon, first_oil.first_oil, first_gas.first_gas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 1st query results in many-to-many-joins: You join every row with PROPNUM n in table #1 to every row with the same PROPNUM n in table #2 and so on.

But as you join the same table multiple times with different WHERE-conditions you can replace it with *conditional aggregation*:

```
select 
    PROPNUM
    ,min(case when (oil+gas+water) > 0 then d_date end) as [first_fluid]
    ,min(case when (oil+gas) > 0 then d_date end) as [first_hydrocarbon]
    ,min(case when (oil) > 0 then d_date end) as [first_oil]
    ,min(case when (gas) > 0 then d_date end) as [first_gas]
from daily_production
group by PROPNUM
```